# How to use .show() and .hide() with opener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window.opener

I have a page with few photos, when a photo is clicked, a div opens using the whole avaliable screen's space to show an album ... like the facebook's photo viewer. Now, I want to press the ESC key and back to the first page ...

PS: inside the div showAlbumDiv I call an Iframe, and by jquery.css property I chance the iframe's src property. Its because i have to passa an variable by get to the album viewer !

im using the following code in the album viewer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //closingDiv
        $(document).keyup(function(e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 27) {


        $('#showAlbumDiv', window.opener).hide();
        $('.allOfIt', window.opener).show();
        $('#showAlbumDiv',window.opener).css('visibility','hidden');    

         }   // esc
    });
```

The opener has the divs allOfIt and showAlbumDiv ....
the online sample is in http://videoarts.com.br/newSite/portifolio ...

only the album viewer: http://videoarts.com.br/newSite/album/40

Any help !?

thns !

Comment: When I go to your first link, how to I get a new window to open that will show this situation?  I can't find how to reproduce the situation on your site.

Comment: just click in a photo ! ... i have no problems with the video viewer which is a jquery plugin ive downloaded somwhere ...
detail: if you open an album and press esc it will escape the div. Thats because the focus is stil on the openER window. if you click in a photo, the focus will be at the openED window, then, i have my problem !

Answer (score 0):

`window.opener` tries to operate on another window - the one that opened this window.  By your comment, it sounds like you're opening a new div in the same window.  If that's the case, then `window.opener` is the wrong code.  You want to operate in the same window and thus don't need to pass a context to the jQuery functions as they default to the current document.

If you do mean to operate on another window, then (as I asked in my comment), please describe how a new window actually gets opened.  Clicking on a photo does not open a new window, it just displays additional content in the current window.

If you're using embedded iframes, then you may want `window.parent`, not `window.opener` to get the parent document.